# cometd: published message to a channel does not show up in subscribed listener

Tags: groovy, cometd

I am trying to publish a test data into the `cometd-demo` server channel `members/hello/`. handshake done, can get a subscribed message on `callback` and can get published message on `publish()` callback. But i can't get that published message on `subscribe()` listener.

---

Groovy Script:

```
import org.cometd.bayeux.Message;
import org.cometd.bayeux.Message.Mutable
import org.cometd.bayeux.client.ClientSessionChannel;
import org.cometd.bayeux.client.ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener;
import org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient
import org.cometd.client.transport.ClientTransport
import org.cometd.client.transport.LongPollingTransport
import org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient as MyHttpClient

ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener mylistener = new Mylistener();

def myurl = "http://localhost:8080/cometd/"

MyHttpClient httpClient = new MyHttpClient();

httpClient.start()

Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();

ClientTransport transport = new LongPollingTransport(options, httpClient);

BayeuxClient client = new BayeuxClient(myurl, transport)

client.handshake(30000)

def channel = client.getChannel("/members/hello/")

channel.subscribe(mylistener,mylistener)  

while (true)

{

    sleep(5000)

    channel.publish( 'hai' )

}

class Mylistener implements ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener {

        public void onMessage(ClientSessionChannel channel, Message message) {

            println message

        }

    }
```

While running this script I can't get the published data on listener even JVM not killed with the `while` loop. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified incorrect channel path in:

```
def channel = client.getChannel("/members/hello/")
```

Channel path cannot end with `/` - it should be `/members/hello`.

Also double check if you use correct URL. I've used very simple CometD server application (https://github.com/wololock/dojo-jetty9-primer) that uses `/dojo-jetty9-primer/` context path, so in my case URL to CometD server was:

```
def url = "http://localhost:8080/dojo-jetty9-primer/cometd/"
```

You can also simplify your script to something like that:

```
import org.cometd.bayeux.Message
import org.cometd.bayeux.client.ClientSessionChannel
import org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient
import org.cometd.client.transport.LongPollingTransport
import org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient

final String url = "http://localhost:8080/dojo-jetty9-primer/cometd/"

final HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()
httpClient.start()

final BayeuxClient client = new BayeuxClient(url, new LongPollingTransport([:], httpClient))
client.handshake()
client.waitFor(1000, BayeuxClient.State.CONNECTED)

final ClientSessionChannel channel = client.getChannel("/members/hello")
channel.subscribe(new MyListener())

while (true) {
    sleep(1000)
    channel.publish("test")
}

class MyListener implements ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener {
    @Override
    void onMessage(ClientSessionChannel channel, Message message) {
        println "[${new Date()}] Received message from channel (${channel.id}): ${message}"
    }
}
```

Especially a part `client.handshake(30000)` can be simplified in your script - you don't have to wait 30 seconds here.

When you run it you will see a new message showing up in the console every 1 second:

```
[Mon Feb 19 10:15:02 CET 2018] Received message from channel (/members/hello): [data:test, channel:/members/hello]
[Mon Feb 19 10:15:03 CET 2018] Received message from channel (/members/hello): [data:test, channel:/members/hello]
[Mon Feb 19 10:15:04 CET 2018] Received message from channel (/members/hello): [data:test, channel:/members/hello]
[Mon Feb 19 10:15:05 CET 2018] Received message from channel (/members/hello): [data:test, channel:/members/hello]
[Mon Feb 19 10:15:06 CET 2018] Received message from channel (/members/hello): [data:test, channel:/members/hello]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Note that this is a CometD bug, that should have normalized the channel name so that `/members/hello/` and `/members/hello` are indistinguishable. Filed https://github.com/cometd/cometd/issues/769 about this.